# labeling axis for parametric terms with plot.gam

Tags: r, plot, gam

I am trying to plot my gam results. The plotting works very well for all the smooth terms (in my case terms 1 to 8) but if I want to plot parametric terms (from 9 onwards), I can't change the axis labels. No matter if I use plot, plot.gam, termplot or text I can't do it. Any tips? Below is the code example

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3), oma=c(1,1,1,1),pty="s",mar=c(4.5,4.5,1,1)) 
# the first three graphs work perfectly
plot.gam(model$gam,select=1,scale=0,pers=TRUE,all.terms=T,shade=T,xlab="Water depth",ylab="") 
plot.gam(model$gam,select=2,scale=0,pers=TRUE,all.terms=T,shade=T,xlab="Bottom current speed",ylab="")
plot.gam(model$gam,select=3,scale=0,pers=TRUE,all.terms=T,shade=T,xlab="Substance",ylab="")
# this graph for the parametric term is plotted but I cannot change axis labels
plot.gam(model$gam,select=9,scale=0,pers=T,all.terms=T,shade=T,xlab="AIS",ylab="")
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data (e.g. `dput()`) and the additional packages you used by editing your question.

Comment: Hi, Below is an example. Of course the model in the example does not make sense but the problem still persist: I can't change axis labels for parametric terms (term B): require(mgcv)
pa <- c(1,rep(0,9))
term_A <- runif(10,9,15)
term_B <- runif(10,1,25)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(pa,term_A,term_B))

mod<-gam(pa~s(term_A,k=3)+term_B,family=binomial,data=data)
summary(mod)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.gam(mod,select=1,all.terms=T,shade=T,xlab="term A",ylab="") 
plot.gam(mod,select=2,all.terms=T,shade=T,xlab="term B",ylab="")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using RStudio you can check the source code of `plot.gam` by hitting the `F2` button. In R execute the `plot.gam` without brackets. Then you can find, that `plot()` is replaced by `termplot()` for some `select` values.
Thus, to maipulate the x-axis labels you have to use `xlabs` instead of `xlab`.

```
require(mgcv) 
pa <- c(1, rep(0, 9))
term_A <- runif(10, 9, 15)
term_B <- runif(10, 1, 25)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(pa, term_A, term_B)) 
mod <- gam(pa ~ s(term_A, k=3) + term_B, family=binomial, data=data) 
summary(mod)
par(mfrow=c(2, 2)) 
# xlab=""
plot.gam(mod, select=1, all.terms=T, shade=T, xlab="your own lab title", ylab="") 
# xlabs=""
plot.gam(mod, select=2, all.terms=T, shade=T, xlabs="your own lab title", ylab="")
```

Comment: Genius, it works!!! Thank you very much, I haven't thought about checking the code

Comment: @MagdaChu you're welcome. Please consider to accept the answer by clicking the check button on the left side. Thanks.

Comment: would you know how to specify the xlim and ylim with termplot()? Doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: should work according `?termplot`. Search for  `ylim`